# Gnucash: how to sum up multiple currencies in placeholder account?

Tags: finance, gnucash

In Gnucash, I want to see how much cash I have in, say, USD. The Cash placeholder account has several sub accounts, for different currencies. Is it possible that the placeholder account shows the sum of all the amounts in the different currencies, using, say, today's exchange rates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does indeed - the "placeholder" account will sum all of the subaccounts, and will convert the values based on the most recent exchange rate you have stored.

Comment: Actually, the relevant, but not self-evident (at least to me), point here is that IF the "most recent exchange rate" is for some reason from today and if it is set to 0, THEN Gnucash does not retrieve new quotes online AND results (correctly) in not counting the amount from the account in this currency into the placeholder.I had to go to the exchange rate editor (tools) to manually delete entries that specified an exchange rate of 0 for today; then Gnucash was able to retrieve the online exchange rate again.